# Android Zxing client

Tags: android, zxing

I'm developing an app to read barcodes and i imported the **ZXing 2.3.0** project and I tested my app in **Samsung Galaxy Express GT-i8730** with **android 4.1.2** and **Sony Xperia M** with **android 4.3**.

Only in **Samsung Galaxy Express GT-i8730** sometimes when the camera is open the app crash and camera freezes and not appear any error in the logcat.

In logcat appears only this:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 5719K, 37% free 11798K/18435K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 47ms
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6783K, 49% free 10266K/19975K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1046K, 44% free 11309K/19975K, paused 14ms+5ms, total 50ms
```

Comment: Please post error log you are getting when app crashes.

Comment: What are you asking? It freezes? Show us some code. The logical has nothing to do with the error. Does it error out? There will be an ANR, post that.

Comment: the problem is when i read barcode onle sometime the camera freeze and app stop then I have to reboot the phone to camera works.